# floor of a Cauchy sequence is Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I am required to show that if $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence then so is $(\operatorname{floor}(a_n))$. **Any hints on how we may go about showing this please do not provide complete solutions.**

Comment: I don't think you are required to show that.

Comment: $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence, $\lfloor \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \rfloor$ is not

Comment: Were you actually required to show that, or did the problem say "prove or give a counterexample"? If the former you need to speak to whoever assigned the problem. If the latter, as seems more likely: In the future don't modify the problem before asking about it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider this particular example:

$$1+(-1)^n \frac1n$$

The sequence converges to $1$, hence it is Cauchy.

Try to examine the floor function.

Answer (score 3):

$\lfloor a_n\rfloor - \lfloor a_m\rfloor \in \mathbb Z$, so for any $0 < \epsilon < 1$ the only way to have $|\lfloor a_n\rfloor - \lfloor a_m\rfloor| < \epsilon$ is to have $|\lfloor a_n\rfloor - \lfloor a_m\rfloor|=0$ which implies both $a_n$ and $a_m$ are between the same two integers. (i.e. there exists a $k \in \mathbb Z$ so that $k \le a_n < k+1$ and $k \le a_m < k+1$).

So for $\{\lfloor a_n\rfloor\}$ to be cauchy is for $\{a_n\}$ to "reach a point" where all the terms are between two integers.  (To be more formal, there must be an $M \in \mathbb N$ and $k \in \mathbb Z$ where $n > M \implies k \le a_n < k+1$).

Must that be true for all Cauchy sequences?  A cauchy sequence must converge to a value/limit but the individual terms can be on either side of the value/limit.  If the limit is an integer you can have the individual terms "get close" it the integer but not always be on one side.

A simple example is $a_n=(-1)^n*\frac 1n$.  Clearly Cauchy and $a_n \to 0$.  But for even $n$, $a_n > 0$ and $\lfloor a_n \rfloor = 0$ but for odd $n$, $a_n < 0$ and $\lfloor a_n \rfloor = -1$.

So the statement is not true.

However if $a_n \to L$ and $L \not \in \mathbb Z$ then statement is true.

Which should be intuitively obvious.  If $a_n$ converges to a point that is between two integers there "comes a point" are all the terms are between the two integers.

Formally:

If $L \not \in \mathbb Z$ then $\rfloor L \lfloor < L < \rfloor L \lfloor + 1$ and if $D = \min(L - \rfloor L \lfloor,\rfloor L \lfloor + 1 - L)$ then, as $\{a_n\}$ is cauchy, for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find an $M$ where for any $n > M$ we have $|a_n - L | < {\min(D, \epsilon)} \le D$.

So if $a_n \ge L$ we have $\rfloor L \lfloor < L \le a_n$ and $a_n-L < \rfloor L \lfloor + 1 - L$ so $a_n <  \rfloor L \lfloor + 1$.

And if $a_n < L$ then we have $L - a_n < L - \rfloor L \lfloor$ so $\rfloor L \lfloor< a_n <L <  \rfloor L \lfloor + 1$.

Either way $\rfloor L \lfloor< a_n  <  \rfloor L \lfloor + 1$ so $\rfloor a_n \lfloor = \rfloor L \lfloor$ and $\rfloor a_n \lfloor\to \rfloor L \lfloor$

Comment: Well done, (+1) from me!